Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 C# windows environment variables do not want to load
I use a windows environment variable in a csproj file
    <Reference Include="Test.Core">
      <HintPath>${SERVER_PATH}\bin\mypath\test.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>

This variable "SERVER_PATH" is set in my Windows environment variable and works on this project.
But on another project exactly the same csproj code it does not work the enviromement variable does not seem to load.
Can this problem come from the TargetFramework?
I tried to restart visual studio, my computer, tried with other env variables it works on one project but not on the other.
I can't find a solution, thank you for your help

Drop to a command prompt and type SET and hit enter. It will display all of your environment variables.  You can also set a variable with that command.

It's better to provide more information about error messages of another project, for example, is it an error during compilation or the project cannot be completely built?Variable "SERVER_PATH" refers to a relative path or an absolute path?


Make sure to use $(MY_VAR) and not curly braces, 2. The "Project System Tools" extention can also help you log the builds and capture "binary logs" of builds - these also show the known environment variables at the beginning of the build. 3 - instances of VS / MSBuild nodes might not get the updated variable if they linger around so be sure to log out and in again if you change it.


Any feedback? @Falcom

Yes was curly braces, thanks for helps !
